# Overflow: hidden not working when TD, and TH width are specified

Tags: html, css, overflow

I need your help.

It seems that my TD cell is not respecting the overflow: hidden in the CSS. I've done everything recommended with the fixed layout of the table as well as specifying the widths of the TH's and TD's

Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">

/*------------------------------------------------------------------
Table Style
------------------------------------------------------------------ */
table a:link {
    color: #666;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration:none;
}
table a:visited {
    color: #999999;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
}
table a:active,
table a:hover {
    color: #bd5a35;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
table {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#666;
    font-size:12px;
    background:#eaebec;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
table th {
    padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #e0e0e0;
    border-right: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    width: 160px;

    background: #ededed;
}
table th:first-child {
    text-align: left;
}
table tr:first-child th:first-child {
    border-left: 0;
}

table tr {
    text-align: center;
}
table td:first-child {
    text-align: left;
    border-left: 0;
}
table td {
    padding:10px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #e0e0e0;
    border-right: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    background: #fafafa;
    width: 130px;
}
table tr:last-child td {
    border-bottom: 0;
}

table tr:hover td {
    background: #f2f2f2;

}

#wrapper {
    width: 740px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border: 1px solid rgb(205,205,205);
}
table thead {
    position:fixed;
}
table td > div {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}


</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">
<table>

    <!-- Table Header -->
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Task Details</th>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Progress</th>
            <th>Vital Task</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <!-- Table Header -->

    <!-- Table Body -->
    <tbody>

        <tr>
            <td>Create</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>100%</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
        </tr><!-- Table Row -->

        <tr>
            <td>Take the dog</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>100%</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
        </tr><!-- Darker Table Row -->

        <tr>
            <td>Waste half</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>20%</td>
            <td>No</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><div>Feel inferior</div></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>80%</td>
            <td>No</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><div>Some long text that shouldn't resize the box</div></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>100%</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><div>Vow to complete</div></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>23%</td>
            <td>yes</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Procrastinate</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>80%</td>
            <td>No</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><a href="#yep-iit-doesnt-exist">Hyperlink Example</a></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>80%</td>
            <td><a href="#inexistent-id">Another</a></td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
    <!-- Table Body -->

</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: overflow should be applied to td or th , else give a width to the div so it can apply overflow (here : td>div{width:100%;overflow:hidden;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just needed to get rid of the white-space here

```
table td > div {
   overflow: hidden;
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

and I added colgroups. They are better for setting widths in your columns and avoid issues

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/2PbLy/)